# Convert Riemann sum to a definite integral: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{{1\over n^2}\left(1+{2k\over n}\right)} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm between 2 answers for this question, but I am not sure if either of them are right.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{{1\over n^2}\left(1+{2k\over n}\right)} $$
It has to be rewritten as a definite integral. I am between $$\int_0 ^1\sqrt{1+2x}dx$$ and $$\int_1^2\sqrt{x}dx$$ Not sure if either of them or right though, help please.

Comment: Write down explicitly the Riemann sums for each, say for $n=5$.  The sums for the first one will fit nicely. The ones for the second will not.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{{1\over n^2}(1+{k\over n})}=\int_1^2\sqrt{x}dx $$

Comment: Is delta x 1/n or 2/n? You can factor out the 1/n^2 from the radical and get 1/n or say that it is f(a+k(delta x)). So it would either be 1/n or 2/n?

Comment: The second answer you got is of a very similar limit, as Razieh pointed out in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

One may recall that for any Riemann integrable function over $[a,b]$, as $n \to \infty$, one has

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(b-a)}nf\left(a+\frac{k(b-a)}n \right) \to \int_a^bf(x)dx
> $$

Then you may apply it to $\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt{1+2x}$, $a=0$, $b=1$ giving the limit
$$
\int_0 ^1\sqrt{1+2x}\:dx.
$$ By the change of variable $1+2x \to u$ you also get
$$
\frac12\int_1^3\sqrt{u}\:du
$$

Comment: But if it is f(a+k(b−a)/n) then shouldn't a = 1 instead of 0?

Comment: If you choose $\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt{1+2x}$, then $a=0$ since the number $1+\ldots$ is already in the function.

Comment: But is the function $$\sqrt{1+2x}$$?

Comment: Please, what becomes $\frac{(b-a)}nf\left(a+\frac{k(b-a)}n \right)$ when $\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt{1+2x}$, $a=0$, $b=1$?

Comment: Then what does 1/n^2 under the radical sign? I factored it out to get 1/n so then delta x would be 1/n.

Comment: Yes it is, you are right, you have $\dfrac{(b-a)}n=\dfrac{(1-0)}n=\dfrac1n$ outside.